# Change the options of a second dropdown based on first dropdown using the bootstrap-select.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-select

I am trying to change the options of a second dropdown list based on the selection of the first dropdown.

The code it works as you can see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/hwp1qw8q/). However because it does not work since I make use bootstrap-select.js. The reason that I added this is to have a nice multiple effect selection.

Apparently, the reason is because it is not anymore a simple `<select>` with `<option>` after the JS, but I do not know how to find a solution on this.

This is the code

```
<select class="form-control" id="choice1">
     <option value="Food">Food</option>
     <option value="Fruit">Fruit</option>
  </select>

<select class="selectpicker" multiple id="choice2">
     <option data-option="Food" value="M">Mustard</option>
     <option data-option="Food" value="M">Ketchup</option>
     <option data-option="Fruit" value="M">Apple</option>
    <option data-option="Fruit" value="M">Orange</option>
  </select>

$("#choice1").change(function() { 
    if(typeof $(this).data('options') === "undefined") {

    $(this).data('options',$('#choice2 option').clone());
    } 
var id = $(this).val();
var options = $(this).data('options').filter('[data-option=' + id + ']');
$('#choice2').html(options);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap-select.js has a `refresh` method you can use. Your JS code will be like:

```
$("#choice1").change(function () {
    if (typeof $(this).data('options') === "undefined") {
        /*Taking an array of all options-2 and kind of embedding it on the select1*/
        $(this).data('options', $('#choice2 option').clone());
    }
    var id = $(this).val();
    var options = $(this).data('options').filter('[data-option=' + id + ']');
    $('#choice2').html(options);
    //Refresh #choice2 to show the new values
    $('#choice2').selectpicker('refresh');
});
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/hwp1qw8q/10/) is a working demo.